# mysql group by with latest record per day

Tags: mysql

Table Name : Log

```
id      |   userid  |       loginDate       |   type    |
---------------------------------------------------------
1       |   1       |   2017-07-01 00:05:50 |   1       |
2       |   1       |   2017-07-01 06:06:50 |   2       |
3       |   2       |   2017-07-01 06:34:50 |   3       |
4       |   3       |   2017-07-01 06:56:76 |   1       |
5       |   2       |   2017-07-01 15:46:52 |   2       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a table like this. so i need to filter last login type count per day

i tried the following query

```
SELECT
  DATE(logindateindividual) AS loginlocaldate,
  typeofattendanceforday    AS typeofattendance,
  count(*)                  AS count
FROM (SELECT
        DATE(logindate) AS logindateindividual,
        type            AS typeofattendanceforday,
        count(*)        AS count
      FROM log
      WHERE logindate BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
      GROUP BY CAST(logindate AS DATE), type, userid) AS data
GROUP BY data.logindateindividual;
```

but it is not giving the latest type.
If a user had more than one login then it is counting the

Result i am getting for above query is

```
loginlocaldate   |   typeofattendance   |   count   | 
-----------------------------------------------------
   2017-07-01    |    1                 |    5      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

My Expectation is

```
loginlocaldate   |   typeofattendance   |   count   | 
-----------------------------------------------------
   2017-07-01    |    1                 |    1      |
-----------------------------------------------------
   2017-07-01    |    2                 |    2      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why does the record with type=3 not show up in the results?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: We have 3 users. so final result's count should be 3. Type 3 was done by user 2. But user 2's last loging type was 2. so the count for type 2 is incremented by 1.